# In a Camunda process, How can I retrieve a boolean value from JSON using JavaScript and Spin?

Tags: javascript, camunda

I have a service task which calls a REST API; the API is returning the following JSON:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": null,
    "details": [],
    "errors": [],
    "transactions": []
}
```

The service task has a JavaScript output parameter to process the JSON output:

```
var statusCode = connector.getVariable("statusCode");
if (statusCode != 200) {
    throw new Error(connector.getVariable("response"));
}
else {
    var output = S(connector.getVariable("response"));
    output.prop("success").value==true;    // Problem line
}
```

I have sent the `output` to a process variable and confirmed that it contains the JSON above.  However, I cannot get this output to ever register as `true` for the subsequent forking of the process.  I have tried all of the following:

```
output.prop("success");
output.prop("success").value;
output.prop("success").value==true;
output.prop("success").value===true;
output.prop("success").value=="true";
```

Can anyone help with getting this right?

Comment: Do you have response header 'Content-Type: application/json'? Is response a string? Do you need to parse it to JSON?

Comment: @marekful - I have an input parameter on the service task: `headers:Map` value `Key='accept'; Value='application/json'`.  Should I add a header in the same place for `Content-Type`?

Comment: Data is generally sent over the HTTP protocol as text. Some applications will automatically convert text to JSON objects when needed depending on response headers but some will not. You need check the what type of data is 'output' once you retrieved it from the connector and JSON.parse() it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help with this in the Camunda forum [here](https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-can-i-retrieve-a-boolean-value-from-json-using-javascript-and-spin/7562/2).  My code now reads as below, and works as desired:

```
var statusCode = connector.getVariable("statusCode");
if (statusCode != 200) {
    throw new Error(connector.getVariable("response"));
}
else {
    var output = S(connector.getVariable("response"), "application/json");
    output .prop("success").boolValue();
}
```